How do I enable script in etc/rc.local to run on startup?
I have a script I want to run on startup (this is for a raspberry pi), and I've followed the instructions in the answer to the same question (linked here).

The code I want to run is in a text file called startup.sh

#!/bin/sh is in the first line of startup.sh. But when I run sudo startup.sh in the terminal to check whether the code is functioning, I get an error that says, "command not found".  I get the same error when I run startup.sh

In /etc/rc.local, I've written sh, then the full pathname to startup.sh followed by exit 0
sh /home/bugs/Desktop/AutoBeetle-BeetleMonitoring/startup.sh

exit 0


verified that the first line in /etc/rc.local is #!/bin/sh -e

ensured /etc/rc.local is executable:
sudo chown root /etc/rc.local
sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.local


verified that the code works:
sudo /etc/rc.local start



When I do this, the code works perfectly. But when I re-boot the system, it still doesn't run on startup. I'm confused why everything works except step 2, and whether that's causing the problems with running on startup. Any help much appreciated.

If you run sudo sh /home/bugs/Desktop/AutoBeetle-BeetleMonitoring/startup.sh, does that work as expected?

What does systemctl is-enabled rc-local.service say?

What steeldriver said, there's also a chance, depending on what the script does, that rc.local is not the appropriate place to start it. E.g., if the script depends on a service which requires a multiuser runlevel. In which case you probably want to write a simple systemd service for it.

sudo systemctl enable rc-local

change to "Type=forking" in /etc/system/systemd/rc-local.service

rc.local is as dead as it can be. Use a systemd Service Unit instead, that's the state of technology for more than 10 years now, plus it gives you way better control about then "when what where who" starting a script, plus you get logging for free via systemd's journald logging demon.

@muru yes, that does work!

@steeldriver it says "enabled-runtime"

@noisefloor it seems like a systemd service unit would work a lot better - I will try that. Any tips on writing one for a complete beginner?

@user23815104 see https://askubuntu.com/a/719157/158442 for a simple unit

If all else fails, consider putting a line in root's crontab:
@reboot /home/bugs/Desktop/AutoBeetle-BeetleMonitoring/startup.sh

One final point, be sure anyone can run the script (ie. permissions 755 or better)

make that 700 and use /etc/crontab so a user is provided to the script.

I don't see using /etc/crontab the better technique for this @reboot situation.  My suggestion remains that the item in question is better placed in the crontab for root.  The difference between /etc/crontab and using root's crontab (sudo crontab -e) might be better explained after reading https://superuser.com/questions/290093/difference-between-etc-crontab-and-crontab-e

Your $PATH at the terminal is not the same as the $PATH in startup scripts, cronjobs, systemd services, etc. Look at the results of  echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias in each of your environments.

(I don't have enough Reputations to comment.)
Try using the full path: /usr/bin/sudo followed by the full path to your script.
(And for maybe a bonus reputation point.)  Use the 'which' command to display the full path:  which sudo.
